# How can I do initial load of side input at the beginning of pipeline, while still refreshing the same side input on regular interval?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am using side input in my apache beam pipeline and I need this side input to be refreshed on regular interval. Currently I am following slowly updating global windows side inputs pattern explained in Apache beam pattern website ([Apache beam pattern references](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/patterns/side-inputs/))

My code looks like this :

```
PCollectionView<Map<String, List<String>>> campaignAudienceMap =
        pipeline.apply(GenerateSequence.from(0).withRate(1, Duration.standardSeconds(60L)))
                .apply(Window.into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(60))))
                .apply(Sum.longsGlobally().withoutDefaults())
                .apply(
                        ParDo.of(
                                new DoFn<Long, Map<String, List<String>>>() {

                                  @ProcessElement
                                  public void process(
                                          @Element Long input,
                                          OutputReceiver<Map<String, List<String>>> o) {
                                    Map<String,List<String>> map = RedisReaderService.readCampaignAudienceData();
                                    o.output(map);
                                    System.out.println("Campaign audience data successfully read");
                                  }
                                }))
                .apply(
                        Window.<Map<String, List<String>>>into(new GlobalWindows())
                                .triggering(Repeatedly.forever(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane()))
                                .discardingFiredPanes())
                .apply(View.asSingleton());
```

Code above refreshes side input every 60 minutes and it works. The issue is that the data load to side input only happens beginning from t+60s, t+120s so on and so forth, with **t** as the the time when pipeline execution begins.

How to make the data load to the **same side input** also happens on **t+0s**,  when pipeline begins execution ?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a source that generates elements every 60 seconds and you group that into 60 second Windows. This window fires at watermark (Window end). I think you could try adding a trigger that fires the 60 second window early. For example,

```
Window.into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(60)).triggering(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane().plusDelayOf(Duration.standardSeconds(1))
```

This would cause the trigger the fire early (one second after the first element is detected.